# Java Bluetooth Proxy

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I’m not sure if this is the right place to ask this question as this is my first question, but I have the following scenario and I need advice and guidance. Or, if this is the wrong place to ask this question, where should I post it?

I want to create a Java Bluetooth proxy application that will sit in the middle of an Android app and a bluetooth IoT device. I want this Java application to see all the traffic that is being exchanged between the app and the IoT device. I have found similar applications called [btproxy](https://github.com/conorpp/btproxy) and [btlejuice](https://github.com/DigitalSecurity/btlejuice), but I want to implement it within Java and I want it to be really simple. I have looked into Bluecove but I'm not having much luck. I’m guessing I will need 2 different machines or VM’s so I can use 2 different bluetooth adapters.
Basically, when you connect the Android app to the computer/VM, the data will be logged and it will be sent to the IoT device. The IoT device will then process it, and send its data back to the Android app via the computer/VM. I’m guessing this relies heavily on the UUID of the app and the device?
Is this possible to achieve, if so, have I got the right topology for this scenario and what would be the best Java API to use and is there any code that will help?